# list all files in sub directory 1 level below?

Tags: tcl

I am trying to list all of the *.tcl files that's exactly 1 level below.
Such as

```
./dirA/x.tcl
./dirB/y.tcl
./dirC/z.tcl
```

I am using `foreach` command to list all files & directories under the sub directory, but the output is empty..

```
foreach dir [glob -type d *] {        
    glob -path ./$dir *    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need one call to glob:

```
set tcl_files [glob */*.tcl]
```

Comment: love it! simplicity at best. I also saw someone used `glob **/*.tcl`, does the double asterisk make a difference?

Comment: @Yonk No; it makes no difference to `glob`. It *does* if you're using a number of tools in the Java ecosystem (where it means “as many directories as you want”) but that's something else entirely.

Answer (score 5):

To begin with, you probably want the `-directory` option rather than the `-path` option. It can be abbreviated to `-dir`. Also, you wanted the files matching `*.tcl`, not every file (`*`).

```
foreach dir [glob -type d *] {        
    glob -dir $dir *.tcl
}
```

Second, the `foreach` command does not collect the results of the script it runs, so you need to do that yourself:

```
set files [list]
foreach dir [glob -type d *] {        
    lappend files {*}[glob -dir $dir *.tcl]
}
```

Now the `files` variable should hold the file names you want.

If you're using an older version of Tcl (before 8.5), you need to write it like this:

```
set files [list]
foreach dir [glob -type d *] {        
    set files [concat $files [glob -dir $dir *.tcl]]
}
```

Documentation: [concat](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/concat.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [glob](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/glob.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Comment: The ``{*}`` syntax was added in Tcl 8.5 not 8.6.